# In the spectrum of a polynomial ring, does $Z(g)\subset Z(f)$ imply $(f)\subset (g)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R=k[x_1,…,x_n]$ a polynomial ring, $f$ a polynomial s.t. $(f)$ a prime ideal, we denote $V$ the zeros of $f$.

My question is, for any irreducible subvariety of $V$ with defined polynomial $g$, does $(g)$ a prime ideal in $R/(f)$ ?

More explicitly, for two primes $(f)$ and $(g)$ in $k[x_1.…,x_n]$, does $Z(g)\subset Z(f)$ implies $(f)\subset (g)$?

Does this still hold if we change $(f)$ and $(g)$ to arbitrary prime ideal $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $Z(P_1)\subset Z(P_2)$?

For some simple case such as $R=k[x,y]$ and $f=y$, it's easy to calculate all the prime ideal, but I have no idea to prove it in general, is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $Z(I)\subset Z(J)$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{J}\subset\sqrt{I}$, and since a prime ideal is radical, we have $J\subset I$.

Answer (score 3):

It does not hold in general that the intersection of irreducibles is irreducible. Imagine you have two curves $C_1,C_2$ in the affine plane $\textbf{A}^2$ (over $\mathbf{C}$), then their intersection is not irreducible.
Take $C_1$ the parabola defined by $(f)=(y-x^2)$ and $C_2$ be a line $(g)=(y-x-2)$. Then $(g)$  in $R/(f)$ defines the quotient $R/(f,g)$, whose spectrum consists of two points $(x+1,y-1),(x-2,y-4)$ (the intersection of the two points) so it is in particular not irreducible.

$\textbf{Edit}$: $V(f) \subset V(g)$ implies that $g$ vanishes along the locus defined by $f$, so $g=fh$ i.e. $(g) \subset (f)$.
In algebraic terms, under the canonical projection $R \rightarrow R/(f)$ $g$ gets mapped to zero, so this map factors over $R/(g) \rightarrow R/(f)$. However, in this situation, for $g$ to be prime it needs not be irreducible (equivalent conditions in UFD's), so you need $h$ to be a unit.

$\textbf{2nd Edit}$ to answer your question: for arbitrary prime ideals in $\textbf{Spec}(R)=\textbf{A}^2$ it works like this: If you cut out by an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbf{C}[x,y]$ you get an irreducible curve $V(f) = \textbf{Spec}(R/f) \subset \mathbf{A}^2$. Now primes in this one-dimensional ring (we lost a dimension by cutting down, see Krulls Hauptidealsatz) are exactly the primes containing $(f)$. This is $(f)$ itself (the generic point of the curve) and $(f) \subsetneq \textbf{p}$ implies that $\textbf{p}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, i.e. a point on the curve $V(f)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but seems in your example Z(g) is not contained in Z(f).

Comment: ok you just rephrased your question: By Z(g) you mean V(g)?

Comment: $g$ can absolutely be prime: take $f=x$ and $g=-x$.

Comment: @Simonsays Yes. Thanks you for your answer! What about the case if we change (f) and (g) to arbitrary prime ideal in R?

Comment: @KReiser Im sorry, thank you. up to units of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$, $g\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

1. If $g\mid f^N$ for some $N\ge 1$, then $Z(g) \subset Z(f)$.
2. Conversely, if $k$ is [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field), and $Z(g)\subset Z(f)$, then there exist $N\ge 1$ such that $g \mid f^N$ ( [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz#Formulation))
3. If $g$ is  irreducible ( so prime, since $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Examples)), then $g \mid f^N$ for some $N\ge 1$ is equivalent to $g\mid f$.
4. Note: Sometime we are confused by the sense of the divisibility/inclusion.  To avoid this, take some extreme cases. $g=1$ always divides $f$, so $\emptyset= Z(1) \subset Z(f)$. Or $g$ always divides $0$, so $Z(g) \subset Z(0) = k^n$.